# Setting text-overflow for table-cell

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make css table with 3 columns and fixed width, say, 200px. **1st** and **2nd** columns' width should be automatically adjusted according to their text's length, but text's length will vary slightly, say, it will be 1 - 4 letters and no more, assume we know that in advance (and that's why `table-layout: auto;`). But for the **3rd** column, text length is not known in advance, it may be very long, and if it is so then it should show single text line gracefully truncated  with "..." on the end, like it happens when set `text-overflow: ellipsis` .

I need something like that:

```
col1 | col2 | col3
----------------------------------------
t    | text | te xt text
text | t    | text
tex  | txt  | long text, long text te...
```

Here's the code I've made till now (or see CodePen here: https://codepen.io/polar11beer/pen/POaadj):

```css
.fixed-width {
  width: 200px;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
}

.table-cell__long-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-width">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        text1
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        text2 text2
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell table-cell__long-text">
        text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently, the 3rd column spreads to all the text length, disregarding the table width. I've tried to set `max-width: 50%;` for it, but no luck. And I'd like to avoid using plain javascript, as it is React app.

All I managed to achieve is wrapping the 3rd column long text into span with fixed height, like this (CodePen https://codepen.io/polar11beer/pen/gXKjoK):

```css
.fixed-width {
  width: 200px;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
}

.table-cell__long-text {
  /* overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; */
}

.long-text-wrapper {
  display: block;
  height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-width">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        text1
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        text2 text2
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell table-cell__long-text">
        <span class="long-text-wrapper">
          text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

But doing this way, it lacks "..." at the end, while I'd prefer to have it.

Comment: I've created a pen with your code and added some jQuery to it: https://codepen.io/Kathara/pen/VrdGZx maybe this will help :)

Comment: @Kathara OP is building a React app... no way they're going to load jQuery in it, especially just for this.

Comment: @Kathara thanks a lot =) , but yes, it's React app, so first I'll try to find a solution without additional javascript.

Comment: @Vasiliy Sorry, I don't know anything about React but maybe you can adapt it with React? It's also Javascript isn't it? Maybe you could do something similar. If not at least I was a little creative today ^^

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand the problem you are facing to wrap text under ellipsis in a table cell, would like to mention that:

- `text-overflow: ellipsis` only works well with `display:block` and not really with any other attribute of `display` property. Hence, assigned `display: block` to the cell which should contain ellipsis truncated text. Also, since width is a must attribute in handling text-overflow conditions, so it has been given.

Let me know if there's something I couldn't catch about the problem statement.

```css
.fixed-width {
  width: 200px;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 40px;
}

.table-cell__long-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-width">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">
        text1
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell">
        text2 text2
      </div>
      <div class="table-cell table-cell__long-text">
        text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3 text3
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```